# jQuery animate and slideDown simultaneously

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slide, simultaneous, sametime

How can I make animate and slide down functions below to happen at exactly same time and duration:

```
current_item.css('margin-left', 0);
current_item.animate({ 'marginLeft': '20px'});
current_item.slideDown(300, 'swing');
```

My code above is animating it before sliding down. If I move animate function below, it is sliding down and then animating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine both `marginLeft` and `height` to be `.animate()`d, like:

```
$("#btn1").one("click", function () {
    var current_item = $("#div1");
    current_item.css('margin-left', 0);
    current_item.animate({
        marginLeft: "20px",
        height: "toggle"
    }, 300, "swing");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/sDrtE/

(yes, I meant to use `.one()` and not `.on()`, because it looks weird if you keep clicking the button)

Comment: thank you very much. That works fine. And I need to slide up and set margin-left to 0 as well. What is equivalent of slideUp in animate function?

Comment: @jCloud Come on now, I already gave you the basic structure - just reverse the value for `marginLeft`: http://jsfiddle.net/sDrtE/2/

Comment: Yeah I did not know that toggle works for hiding too. But I used height: "hide" instead of toggle to slideUp the block

Comment: @jCloud Ahh I see. Well here's a more full "toggle" way of doing it (if you care): http://jsfiddle.net/cfTXd/